# Running built-in beep sound from background process on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, powershell, command-line

I have a background service that's executing a java program on a Windows 10 machine.

I'm trying to make to built-in speaker beep.
I found that the command
`powershell [console]::beep()` works as I want to, but only when I'm executing it directly in the cmd terminal.
Or if I launch my program from the command line.

The java program executes:
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c powershell [console]::beep()");`

My problem is that the speaker doesn't beep when the the java process is launched in the background via a service.

Is there a permission problem that blocs the process from accessing the speaker output ?
Or is `[console]` undefined when executing in the background so powershell can't execute the beep command ?

Comment: Your Java code is probably throwing an exception when it tries to execute the [powershell] command when it is run as a [Windows] service. My guess is that when your code runs as a [Windows] service, its environment is different to that when you run your code from the [command prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). Try providing the full path to `powershell.exe` and note that you don't need `cmd /c` in order to execute a PowerShell command, just call `powershell.exe` directly.

Comment: What about using `java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();` to create the sound?

Comment: What account are you using to run service?  The default account is System which doesn't have an environment.  Normal solution is to create a service account and then run service using the service account instead of the default system account.